# Method to Prevent ' from turning into &quot;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following line:

```
data: <%= @product_count.to_json %>
```

which renders:

```
data: [[&quot;name1&quot;,20],
      [&quot;name2&quot;,9],
      [&quot;name3&quot;,18],
      [&quot;name4&quot;,32],
      [&quot;name5&quot;,28],
      [&quot;name6&quot;,17],
      [&quot;name7&quot;,11]]
```

in the view. How do I change this so I get the actual quotes instead of the HTML.

The data comes from this line:

```
period_registration_product.each do |key, value|
      @product_count << [Product.find_by_id(key).name, value]
end
```

Update:

I tried: `data: <%= JSON.parse(@product_count.to_json) %>` and it failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up using:  `data: <%= @product_count.to_json.html_safe %>`

I tried both `h` and `raw` and neither of those worked, however, `html_safe` did it.

Not sure why, but for future travelers I'm on rails version 3.2.7.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
data:    <%= raw @product_count.to_json %>
```

or

```
data:    <%= @product_count.to_json.html_safe %>
```

Comment: PriteshJ, I actually tried both of those and got two different results. `raw` did not work, but `html_safe` did.

Comment: ya I read it , I am looking for some good differences between them but cant find one. i just could understand `raw` calls `safe_concat` to render. but both of them do almost the same work may be we need some rails guy to explain more

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CGI::unescapeHTML](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescapeHTML)

```
> CGI::unescapeHTML("Usage: foo &quot;bar&quot; &lt;baz&gt;")
=> "Usage: foo \"bar\" <baz>"
```

and convert it back.I don't know how to prevent it.

The above solution worked for me.For more try this [link](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/80431).Hope this helps.

Comment: Like this: `<%= CGI::unescapeHTML(@product_count.to_json) %>` ? That doesn't seem to have any effect:

Comment: Try this [Library](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/).Sample code: require 'htmlentities'

HTMLEntities.new.decode("&gt;") # =>  ">"
HTMLEntities.new.encode(">") # => "&gt;"

Comment: It seems to me that I shouldn't need an external library to handle this.

Comment: Ya you are right.In older versions we need that library now it comes built in.So no need.Tell me it works or not?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where the data is coming from could you mark it as [raw](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw) so that it is not html escaped?

Comment: I've added the above, but I saw someone suggest that earlier and that didn't work. It left everything unmodified.